# How to interpret a scatter plot for the whole model in a linear multiple regression analysis?

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, scatterplot

I am writing a very basic report on ability of three predictors (two dichotomous and one continuous) to predict the criterion. I created a scatter plot for the whole model, and all I have to do is write 1 or 2 very simple sentences on what it suggests. Would it be appropriate to state that the many residuals suggest that this may be a weak model? Is there anything else I should pay special attention to? [Please bear in mind this is a very basic report; I am not expected to write anything in depth; I am using SPSS].

Many, many thanks to whoever answers.

Comment: Did you really mean to say "many residuals" and not "large size of residuals" or something like that? After all, by definition, there will *always* be exactly as many residuals as there are data being fitted. I am also curious what you mean by a "scatter plot for the whole model," given that at least five variables are now in evidence: three predictors, a predictand, and the residuals. Which two of those do you propose to show in the scatterplot?

Comment: If you'd like to post your plot but find the site doesn't give you permission, you can send it to me and I'll post it.